# fundamental theory of calculus - can't grasp the prove. why tend to zero?

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone explain me, please, why [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) says:

> $$ \left|f(x)-\frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}\right|=\frac{|Excess|}{h}\leq
>  \frac{h\left(f(x+h_1)-f(x+h_2)\right)}{h}=f(x+h_1)-f(x+h_2) $$ By the
> continuity of $f$, the right-hand expression tends to zero as $h$ does

What is the right-hand expression - $\frac{|Excess|}{h}$ ?

But if $\frac{|Excess|}{h}$ tends to zero , so $\frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}$ must tends to zero too...

And what does "continuity of $f$" have to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x+h_1)$ is the maximum value of $f$ on $[x,x+h]$, and $f(x+h_2)$ is the mininum value. Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, both these values approach $f(x)$ as $h\to 0$.

If $f$ fails to be continuous at $x$, this won’t be the case. Consider the point $x=0$ and the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & x\le 0 \\ 1, & x>0\end{cases}$.

Look at the picture. You can see that $A(x+h)-A(x)$ is far greater than the excess. Only when you subtract $f(x)h$ do you get the excess.

**EDIT**: Since you're having such trouble believing the proof on Wiki, I'm going to give the argument that I prefer to give, which is simpler. We don't need to even think about the "excess."  If $h>0$, let $M_h$ be the maximum (or least upper bound) of $f$ on $[x,x+h]$ and let $m_h$ be the minimum (or greatest lower bound) of $f$ on $[x,x+h]$. If $h<0$, use the same notation for the maximum/minimum of $f$ on $[x+h,x]$. Then here is the crucial inequality:
$$m_hh \le A(x+h)-A(x) \le M_hh  \quad\text{when } h>0$$
(because the area under the curve on the the interval $[x,x+h]$ is trapped between rectangles with base $h$ and respective heights $m_h$ and $M_h$).
Similarly,
$$m_h(-h) \le A(x)-A(x+h) \le M_h(-h) \quad\text{when } h<0.$$
Therefore,
$$m_h\le \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}h \le M_h.$$
As I said earlier, since $f$ is continuous at $x$, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} m_h=f(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} M_h$. By the famous squeeze property, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}h = f(x)$.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but are you sure this is a rigorous proof? Isn't it too naive to draw general conclusions from one particular picture? Can we be sure that $h\left(f(x+h_1)-f(x+h_2)\right)$ << $A(x+h)-A(x)$  absolutely in all cases?  Couldn't it be that $h\left(f(x+h_1)-f(x+h_2)\right)$ is just slightly less than $A(x+h)-A(x)$ - then we could say that both $\frac{|Excess|}{h}$ and $\frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}$ tend to zero.

Comment: You've got inequalities messed up here, and you're forgetting the $f(x)$ that is crucial in this discussion. $\frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}h$ is tending to $f(x)$. That's the whole point here. I'm going to add my preferred proof as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, this is more intuitive. I guess I have to understand thoroughly what "continuity of a function" means and what its properties are.

Answer (score 0):

I find Wikipedia’s proof a little unsatisfactory, since it assumes continuity on the whole interval, when in reality, that is unnecessary. We can prove the following theorem directly by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity at a point, and basic properties of integrals:

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a Riemann-integrable function and define $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ by the formula $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$. If $f$ is continuous at a point $x\in [a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x$, and $F’(x)=f(x)$ (if $x=a$ or $x=b$, interpret these statements as one-sided limits).

For the proof, let us assume for convenience that $x\in (a,b)$ (the other cases can be handled similarly). Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By definition of continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $t\in [a,b]$, if $|t-x|\leq \delta$, then $|f(t)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon$. Now, for this $\delta$, consider any $0<|h|<\delta$. Then,
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}-f(x)\right|
&=\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}[f(t)-f(x)]\,dt\right|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{|h|}\int_{\min(x,x+h)}^{\max(x,x+h)}|f(t)-f(x)|\,dt\\
&\leq \frac{1}{|h|} \int_{\min(x,x+h)}^{\max(x,x+h)}\epsilon\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{|h|}\cdot |h|\epsilon\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this shows $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ exists and equals $f(x)$, i.e $F$ is differentiable at $x$, and $F’(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: that's too complicated and confusing for my math level